# What is the difference between socket.send() and socket.sendall()?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm confused about `socket.send()` and `socket.sendall()` functions in Python. As I understand from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) `send()` function uses TCP protocol and `sendall()` function uses UDP protocol for sending data. I know that TCP is more reliable for most of the Web Applications because we can check which packets are sent and which packets are not. That's why, I think use of `send()` function can be more reliable rather than `sendall()` function.

At this point, I want to ask what is the exact difference between these two functions and which one is more reliable for web applications?

Thank you.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear IMO - `.send()` may not send all the data you give it, whereas `sendall()` will not return until all data has been sent - but this may take longer. Generally speaking you should use `sendall()` unless you know that you need to use `.send()`.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**socket.send** is a low-level method and basically just the C/syscall method [send(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/send) / [send(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send). It can send less bytes than you requested, but returns the number of bytes sent.

**socket.sendall** is a high-level Python-only method that sends the entire buffer you pass or throws an exception. It does that by calling `socket.send` until everything has been sent or an error occurs.

If you're using TCP with blocking sockets and don't want to be bothered
by internals (this is the case for most simple network applications),
use sendall.

And python docs:

> Unlike send(), this method continues to send data from string until
>   either all data has been sent or an error occurs. None is returned on
>   success. On error, an exception is raised, and **there is no way to
>   determine how much data**, if any, was successfully sent

Credits to Philipp Hagemeister for brief description I got in the past.

**edit**

`sendall` use under the hood `send` - take a look on [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/65e6c1eff3dde469256df909847b0e9126d0c255/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3562) implementation. Here is sample function acting (more or less) like `sendall` :

```
def sendall(sock, data, flags=0):
    ret = sock.send(data, flags)
    if ret > 0:
        return sendall(sock, data[ret:], flags)
    else:
        return None
```

or from [rpython (pypy source)](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/fd211d1194e8502f4eeffd919a0a4b31d688d324/rpython/rlib/rsocket.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#rsocket.py-914):

```
def sendall(self, data, flags=0, signal_checker=None):
    """Send a data string to the socket.  For the optional flags
    argument, see the Unix manual.  This calls send() repeatedly
    until all data is sent.  If an error occurs, it's impossible
    to tell how much data has been sent."""
    with rffi.scoped_nonmovingbuffer(data) as dataptr:
        remaining = len(data)
        p = dataptr
        while remaining > 0:
            try:
                res = self.send_raw(p, remaining, flags)
                p = rffi.ptradd(p, res)
                remaining -= res
            except CSocketError, e:
                if e.errno != _c.EINTR:
                    raise
            if signal_checker is not None:
                signal_checker()
```