# No body in answer of GET request

Tags: python, http, get, request

I am trying to send the following HTTP GET request: 
GET /test-page/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ##my-server-ip##

The answer I receive contains no body :
received data: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 17:40:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 17:40:20 GMT
ETag: "25-570bcbd95c140"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: text/html

Here is the full python code who makes the request :

```
import socket
import ssl
addr = ('##server-ip##',443)
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
MESSAGE = "GET /test-page/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ##server-ip##\r\n\r\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ss = ssl.wrap_socket(s,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ss.connect(addr)
ss.send(MESSAGE)
data = ss.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
ss.close()
print "received data:", data
```

When I go with Firefox on this page I get the correct body of course...
What is happening please ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide the code that you used to make the request. As it stands it could very well be because the http fairies decided not to return the result.

Comment: Hi scrappedcola, I edited the post with the request code

Comment: I suspect you want to use sendAll vs send, but I'm shaky on python sockets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252273/what-is-the-difference-between-socket-send-and-socket-sendall

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result with sendall function...

Comment: But does it throw an error?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `/test-page/` with `/test-page` ? By the way you should use `sendall`

Comment: No error with sendall. With /test-page I get a "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" error from Apache.

Comment: What happens if you open `/test-page` in browser ?

Comment: It gets automatically redirected to /test-page/ and I get the display of the HTML body.

Comment: I tested the request on this website https://apitester.com/ and I get the right body as an answer. So the issue is for sure on the python side...