# Python HL7 Listener socket message acknowledgement

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, hl7, mllp

I am trying to create HL7 listener in python. I am able to receive the messages  through socket , but not able to send valid acknowledgement

```
ack=u"\x0b MSH|^~\\&|HL7Listener|HL7Listener|SOMEAPP|SOMEAPP|20198151353||ACK^A08||T|2.3\x1c\x0d MSA|AA|153681279959711 \x1c\x0d"
ack = "MSH|^~\&|HL7Listener|HL7Listener|SOMEAPP|SOMEAPP|20198151353||ACK^A08||T|2.3 \r MSA|AA|678888295637322 \r"
ack= bytes(ack,'utf-8')
```

Python code :

```
def listner_hl7():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 4444))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        clientSocket, addr = s.accept()
        message = clientSocket.recv(2048)
        id = (str(message.splitlines()[0]).split('|')[9])

        print('received {} bytes from {}'.format(
            len(message), addr))

        print('sending acknowledgement: ')
        ack = b"\x0b MSH|^~\\&|HL7Listener|HL7Listener|SOMEAPP|SOMEAPP|20198151353||ACK^A08||T|2.3\x1c\x0d MSA|AA|" + bytes(
            id, 'utf-8') + b" \x1c\x0d"

        clientSocket.send(ack)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your *complete* acknowledge is not being sent. You are using `clientSocket.send(ack)`.

Use `clientSocket.sendall(ack)` instead.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34252690/5779732) answer from @kwarunek for more details.

> **socket.send** is a low-level method and basically just the C/syscall method [send(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/send) / [send(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send). It can send less bytes than you requested, but returns the number of bytes sent.
>
> **socket.sendall** is a high-level Python-only method that sends the entire buffer you pass or throws an exception. It does that by calling `socket.send` until everything has been sent or an error occurs.
>
> If you're using TCP with blocking sockets and don't want to be bothered by internals (this is the case for most simple network applications), use `sendall`.

Answer (score -1):

try adding enter in front of MSA|AA in the \n syntax I think it works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30678156)