# How to send multiple messages over same socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets, hl7, mllp

I am trying to send an array of messages through the same socket connection, but I get an error.

Here is my client code:

```
def send_over_socket(hl7_msg_array):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((config.HOST, config.PORT))

    for single_hl7_msg in hl7_msg_array:
        sock.send(single_hl7_msg.to_mllp().encode('UTF-8'))
        received = sock.recv(1024*1024)
        print("Sent: ", received)

    sock.shutdown()
    sock.close()
```

While debugging the code, I see that the exception occurs when I call the `sock.recv(1024*1024)` for the second message.

Here is the error:

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Server-side code:

```
def run_mllp_server():

    class PDQHandler(AbstractHandler):
        def reply(self):
            msg = hl7.parse(self.incoming_message)
            msg_pid = msg[1][3]
            msg_key = msg[2][3][0][1]
            msg_value = msg[2][5]

            lock = RLock()
            lock.acquire()
            results_collection[str(msg_pid)][str(msg_key)] = str(msg_value)
            lock.release()
            print("Received: ", repr(self.incoming_message))
            return parse_message(self.incoming_message).to_mllp()

    # error handler
    class ErrorHandler(AbstractErrorHandler):
        def reply(self):
            if isinstance(self.exc, UnsupportedMessageType):
                print("Error handler success 1")
            else:
                print("Error handler else case")

    handlers = {
        'ORU^R01^ORU_R01': (PDQHandler,),
        'ERR': (ErrorHandler,)
    }

    server = MLLPServer(config.SOCKET_HOST, config.SOCKET_PORT, handlers)
    print("Running Socket on port ", config.SOCKET_PORT)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Here I am using MLLP protocol which has a TCP connection behind the scenes.

Can you help me please figure out what is going on? Is it a problem of ACK?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know python at all but...

I do not think multiple messages is your problem. Looking at exception, I guess your first message is being sent correctly. Then, your client code waits for ACK to be received; but server never sends it. It instead closes the connection.

Also, make sure that whether [`sendall`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57625951/5779732) should be used instead of `send`.

After above issue is fixed, to send multiple messages on same connection, you have to follow [MLLP](http://healthstandards.com/blog/2007/05/02/hl7-mlp-minimum-layer-protocol-defined/) (also called LLP) so that server can differentiate the message.

```
Description                 HEX     ASCII   Symbol
Message starting character  0B      11      <VT>
Message ending characters   1C,0D   28,13   <FS>,<CR>
```

This way, when you send a message to Listener (TCP/MLLP server), it looks for Start and End Block in your incoming data. Based on it, it differentiates each message.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250840/5779732) answer for more details.

Comment: It seems that the server closes the connection after receiving the first message, and I am not able to solve this problem for a long time. If in the client side I put these 2 lines of code inside the for loop, everything works:
`sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` `sock.connect((config.HOST, config.PORT))`

Comment: but I don't want to open array.size() sockets, do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: @AndrewT: Sorry; I do not know python. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250840/5779732) is some C# code you may refer.